# Override Java Method with Generics return type in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics

I am having the following interface in java

```
public interface Action<T extends InfoType> {
    T performAction(String value, Optional<Map<String, String>> params);
}
```

I wanted to know how i can implement this interface having generics in return type in a scala class. I tried the following option. But its giving me type missmatch

```
class MyAction extends Action[MyInfoType] {
  override def performAction(value: String, params: Optional[_]) = {
    new MyInfoTypeImpl()
  }
}
```

Its giving me the following error.

> Error:(12, 5) type mismatch;  found   :
>   com.mycompany.MyInfoTypeImpl
>    required: T
>       new MyInfoTypeImpl()

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When I fill in the blanks in your code (i.e. missing imports and definitions of `InfoType`, `MyInfoType` etc.), I get an error because `Optional[_]` can't be used instead of `Optional[Map[String, String]]`. After fixing that, it compiles fine. I can't reproduce your error message.

Comment: @sepp2k same here. I fixed the imports of java.util.Optional and java.util.Map and it all compiled just fine